# Am not seeing CAPTCHA codes

Tags: support

Win xp sp 3 FF 9, ABP disabled

I just got prompted with the "are you human?" page but the captchas were not visible

Answer (score 2):

Are you using HTTPS-Everywhere?  This has been known to cause problems.

> Specific problem and fix found:
>
> HTTPS-Everywhere forces the use of the secure reCAPTCHA API. The problem with this is the invalid certificate used; specifically, it is expired as of 09-05-04 13:32:04 (GMT).
>
> This can be worked around by navigating to https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/ and adding a permanent exception for the certificate.
>
> Tested on Firefox 4 final on Ubuntu 10.10 to https://superuser.com/captcha.
>
> ---
>
> Courtesy of [Hello71](https://meta.superuser.com/users/36565/hello71) on [Super User's meta](https://meta.superuser.com/a/2460/42458)

Comment: I think it may be related to the well intentioned but awful "disconnect" add in for FF, which also appeared to block google maps